# Win Phone 8 Textblock line limit issue

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textblock

I have been working on wp8 app. My problem about textblock line. When I open a property I can see first 77 lines. But some properties really long and if it pass 77 lines I can't see after lines!

#### My Code

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Poetries}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" Foreground="#362104" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

I hope I can explain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for you. The same problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx